# Email authentication in raw PHP language

Tags: php, authentication

I have an online site that is MVC and written in raw PHP language
I have a register page which is for registration
I want to use the email authentication service
But I don't know
I would be grateful if you could send me a site or resource that is free along with the tutorial
If more details are needed, please provide them
thank you

Comment: do you mean like auth0? or are you trying to get an example of creating user logins with email as username? Your question is very vague. you could also be asking how to verify that an email is real (email verification)??

Comment: I want the code to be sent to the e-mail when the user logs in to register, and if it is correct, it should be activated

Comment: so it is verification and not authentication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Email Verification System is a reliable method for validating email addresses. In this case, you must create a token when a user registers and send it along with the application URL to the user's inbox. However, you must also store the token along with the user ID in the database so that it can be validated later.

You can validate in a variety of ways, but I personally like to create a column in the user database called `is_email_verified` and set its default value to `0`. Then, when the user has successfully registered, I send the email. When the user clicks the verification link, I will use `$_GET` to get the token from the url and check it against the database. Then, using the token, I will get the user id and set the value of that users `is_email_verified` property to `1`.

For your reference you can watch this video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aCrGIFspU4A